# can't connect to database in second form c#

Tags: c#, localdb

I am trying to connect database in project have multiple windows form connection to the first form to database is working fine but when is try to access database inside second form i get error

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\mydatabsename.mdf failed.A database with same name exist,or specified file cannot be opened,or it is located on UNC share.

Connection in first form is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
```

I use same connection in second form

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;")
```

Please help me

Comment: does your `second form` exists in the same directory where `First Form` is??

Comment: yes second form also exists in same directory

Comment: Try changing `AttachDbFilename` to `Initial Catalog` with complete path. See if this solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for replay but i got another error cannot open database "MydatabaseName" requested by login.The Login failed login failed user 'Asus\asus' asus is my user name

Comment: Use a single SqlConnection and share it across your forms.

Comment: My problem solved temporarily by copying database file to c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\mydatabsename.mdf